# Google Translate menu on website not working on iPad

Tags: javascript, css, ipad, google-translate

I'm doing some iPad optimization work on this test URL:
http://www.cherrystoneauctions.com/test

However, I notice that the Google Translate menu at the top-right is not working on my iPad. I can display the list of languages, but if I touch one of them, the menu disappears and the language selection is not made.

I would have thought Google's code would work on iPad. Is there something I am doing wrong (or that I can correct) or is this a limitation of Google Translate?

Answer (score 2):

The Google Translate element requires Flash to work.  As iOS devices do not have Flash, this will not work by design.

[Source](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/977178)

Additionally, I was able to further verify this functionality by successfully using the element using the Puffin Free web browser, which is a Flash-enabled browser.